# Why did systemd decide to start adb

Tags: systemd, services, adb

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS system.

This system, has NEVER had an Android device connected to it, via USB.

Still, to my surprise, I see that **adb** is running:

```
# ps -efa | grep adb
bram       72062    1421  0 Oct29 ?        00:04:07 adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 7
```

And the PPID is the [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) process.

Now... why did systemd decide to fire up a server for adb? I never asked for this to happen?

(Kudos to [powertop](https://01.org/powertop/), btw, for highlighting adb, which shows up as an energy waster, to boot!)

Does Ubunutu LTS have adb enabled as a server, by default? I find that hard to believe? Why? Just in case the user has an Android phone?

How can I disable adb from getting launched automatically?

**UPDATE:**

```
$ systemctl status adb.service
Unit adb.service could not be found.
```

After a reboot, the adb process did not come back.

Further examination revealed that adb was started by systemd on behalf of [renderdoc](https://renderdoc.org/) and renderdoc leaves it running after exit.

Comment: Please investigate a bit more. After you discover the name of the service, use `systemctl status <name>.service` to learn the path of the .service file. Then `dpkg -S /path/to/the/<name>.service` file will tell you which package provided the adb server. The service name, path, and package name would be very useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that adb, even though started by systemd, was started by a request from the [renderdoc](https://renderdoc.org/) tool.

I had an old copy of adb in my user's bin directory, where it got picked up by renderdoc.

After exiting renderdoc, the adb server is left up.

So adb is not brought up at boot time, but at renderdoc's request. This is because the tool can capture both local GPU streams as well as remote ones from Android devices.

Comment: now that you said it, I think UE5 UnrealEditor may be starting it too as `systemctl --type=service` has nothing adb related and the version matches the adb I installed for UE

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thats bold. I've checked my Ubuntu 20.04 and have no such service running. The only thing I did was to remove "snap" but I can't imagine that this would be responsible for the service.

But you can stop that service. First try to find those services running:

`systemctl --type=service`

If you*ve found that service (e.g adb.service) then execute in a terminal:

`sudo systemctl stop adb.service` //this stops the service right away

`sudo systemctl disable adb.service` //will disable it forever

(The name of the service might be another one. "adb" is just an example)

In case you're not sure about the service just edit your question and paste the contents of the first command...